# Continuity from left and right limits, and arbitrary quantities in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, continuity

We are asked to prove the following:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function defined on $R^1$ which satisfies $\lim_{h\to 0} [f(x+h) - f(x-h)]=0$ for every $x \in R^1$. Does this imply $f$ is continuous?

Let's **pretend** we are trying to prove it does imply continuity. Since the assumption about $f$ suggests that $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(x-h) = q$, the task is then to show that the above assumption implies that $q=f(x)$.

It seems reasonable to say that for any given $x$, we can choose $y\in R^1$ such that $y=x+h$, leading to $\lim_{h\to 0} f(y-h)= \lim_{h\to 0} f(x) = f(x)$...

But I am concerned that it is illogical to define any $y$ as such, since $h$ is in a sense a "dynamic" entity, and it seems like a sort of hack to respond to this by continually modifying what $y$ is in the argument.

For instance, imagine a rebuttal where someone says, "Actually, we would have to write $\lim_{h'\to 0} f(y-h')$ which would give us $\lim_{h'\to 0} f(x+(h-h'))$, because we had a fixed $h$."

But then couldn't I just say, "Well, then just make $h$ smaller, to match $h'$."

I recognize that it does not indeed imply continuity, but **my question is concerning the overall style of reasoning here**, and why it is false precisely.

Comment: try to prove the contrapositive, it seems easier. The problem is that you need to justify here that $$\lim_{h\to0}[f(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0\implies \lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)=\lim_{h\to 0} f(x-h)$$ A "suggestion" is not a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Take the function defined as
$$f(x) = 0 \text{ if } x \neq 0, \quad f(0) = 1$$
Then $f(0+h) - f(0-h) = 0$ for all $h > 0$, so the limit for $h \rightarrow 0$ is $0$. If $x \neq 0$, since $h \rightarrow 0$ you can always take $h$ small enough such that $x+h, x-h$ do not hit $0$ as $h$ varies. Then $f(x+h)-f(x-h) = 0$ and the limit still holds. However, $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Please see my edit to see my question regarding the overarching flaw in reasoning used in my faux-proof

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get your rebuttal. The point is that, based on the exercise, you cannot be sure that writing $f(x)$ makes sense. So what you write about $f(y-h) \rightarrow f(x)$ is wrong in general, because, as in my example, you could get that $0 \rightarrow 1$. Further, you cannot fix $h$, as it will go to $0$. Hope this helps. Let me know.